# dynamic age field based on number of children selected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am trying to create a form field to get the number of adults and children. Based on the number of children, I need to show a select field to know the age of those children. I could create a field for adding and removing number of adults and children and could show the field for age based on the total number of children but could not save their age.

Here is how i have done

```
const Form = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Formik
        initialValues={{
          traveller: {
            adult: 1,
            children: 0,
            childAge: []
          }
        }}
      >
        {({ handleSubmit, values }) => {
          return (
            <>
              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                {JSON.stringify(values, null, 2)}
                <TravellerField values={values} />
              </form>
            </>
          );
        }}
      </Formik>
    </>
  );
};

export default Form;

const Index = ({ values }) => {
  return (
    <>
      <Dropdown>
        <Dropdown.Header style={{ width: 400 }}>
          {() => {
            return (
              <div>
                <Button type="button">
                  {values.traveller.adult} adult
                  {values.traveller.children} children
                </Button>
              </div>
            );
          }}
        </Dropdown.Header>
        <Dropdown.Menu
          menuStyle={{
            top: "40px",
            width: 400,
            left: 0,
            right: 0
          }}
        >
          <Dropdown.Item>
            <Wrapper>
              <Inline>
                <Text>Adult</Text>
                <Field name="traveller.adult" component={QuantityField} />
              </Inline>
              <Inline>
                <Text>Children</Text>
                <Field name="traveller.children" component={QuantityField} />
              </Inline>
              {values.traveller.children > 0 &&
                Array.from({ length: values.traveller.children }, (_, i) => {
                  return (
                    <React.Fragment key={i}>
                      <Field name="traveller.childAge" component="select">
                        <option />
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                      </Field>
                    </React.Fragment>
                  );
                })}
            </Wrapper>
          </Dropdown.Item>
        </Dropdown.Menu>
      </Dropdown>
    </>
  );
};
```

To be more clear on what I tried, I have created a sandbox and here is the link to it

https://codesandbox.io/s/green-moon-pehc1?file=/src/Form.js:115-655

This is what i exactly wanted https://www.expedia.com/?pwaLob=wizard-hotel-pwa-v2 if you look at the traveller field of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the name of child age dropdown field to use the index

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-field-array-issue-fix-mr3tx?file=/src/commons/TravellerField/index.js:1458-1814)

**Like this**

```js
                     <Field
                        name={`traveller.childAge[${i}]`} // <---like this
                        component="select"
                      >
                        <option />
                        <option value="5">5</option>
                        <option value="6">6</option>
                        <option value="7">7</option>
                      </Field>
```

[Read more](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/guides/arrays#arrays)